# Fill a matrix from a matrix of indices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to fill a matrix from an array of indices :

```
import numpy as np

indx = [[0,1,2],[1,2,4],[0,1,3],[2,3,4],[0,3,4]]
x = np.zeros((5,5))
for i in range(5):
    x[i,indx[i]] = 1.
```

The result is :

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])
```

As desired.

## Question

Is there a way to do this in pure python/numpy without looping ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) after intialization -

```
x[np.arange(len(indx))[:,None], indx] = 1
```

Comment: That was fast (less than 3 minutes?), Thanks ! I couldn't manage to find this by myself.. :)